# Don't show invalid UI state when data is loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue 2.6.X app I have single-file components such as:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="users.length">
      <!-- render the users in a list -->
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Warning: no users were found
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import userService from '@/services/user-service'

export default {
  name: 'UserList',
  async created () {
    this.users = userService.loadUsersFromServer()
  },
  data () {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A problem with this approach is that after the component renders but before the users are loaded, the warning message is briefly shown in the UI. Is there a recommended way to avoid this "flash of invalid UI state"?

One approach is to introduce a `loading` data prop that is initialised to true, then set to false when the AJAX request has completed, and change the template to

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading">
      Users are loading, please wait....
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="users.length">
      <!-- render the users in a list -->
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Warning: no users were found
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this simple example, this should work fine, but if we need to wait on multiple requests before showing the UI, it could become cumbersome, is there a better/simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all()` to wait on multiple promises before setting loading to false.

That is simplest and what I do most of the times

Or you can defer navigation until the data is loaded if you use router